# What is the spelling of this hand written name?

Tags: palaeography, surnames, marriage-records, kentucky

The 31 Dec 1814 marriage of Moses Ragan and Miss Polly Walker in Nelson, Kentucky, United States [shown here](https://familysearch.org/pal:/MM9.1.1/V5ZD-VZG) states:

> Know all men by these presents, that we Moses Ragan & Charles Walker are held and firmly bound unto the Commonwealth of Kentucky, in the sum of fifty pounds current money; to be paid to the said Commonwealth, to which payment well and truly to be made, we bind ourselves, our heirs, ex'ors and adm'ors, jointly and severally by these presents; sealed with our seals and dated this 01 day of Dec 1814 The condition of the above obligation is such, that if there is no lawful cause to obstruct a marriage, intended to be solemniaed shortly, between the above bound Moses Ragan & Miss Polly Walker daughter of Martha Walker then the above obligation to be void; else to remain in full force. Witness Ben Grayson Seal Moses Ragan Charles Walker
>
> License: This is to certify that I am willing for a license to issue for the marriage of Moses Ragan to my daughter Polly Walker. Given under any law and seal this 31st day of Dec. 1814. Witness Charles Walker Susanna **Remey** Seal: Martha Walker

Can anyone make out the spelling of the last name of Susanna, `Remey`, more precisely?

[image]

The complete image:

[image]

Comment: Looks like Remey to me too, likely to be Remy on other records but I'm sure you probably already know that.

Comment: Could you show a much larger portion of the handwritten text, so people might be able to compare the characters in Susanna's name?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin I don't think that helps here since I believe it is a signature.  Do you see otherwise in [the linked document](https://familysearch.org/pal:/MM9.1.1/V5ZD-VZG)?

Comment: @WilliamKF No, nothing. At both linked documents I saw ads for some genealogy software, which was doubly irritating.

Could you show a large portion of the text, which almost certainly will help here because it's hand written and traditionally, signatures were less distinct from ordinary text than they are today.

Either way, could you drop the links and show a large portion of the text?

What is fairly clear in your post is that the signature isn't Susanna Remey… possibly Remiy or even Remly but almost never, Remy.

Could you show a much larger portion of the handwritten text?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Full image added.  Weird that FamilySearch.org gives you ads, I've never seen any on their site.  I was thinking a different person wrote the text than the person whose signature is shown.

Comment: Thanks for that trouble, William.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears spelling as `Susanna Remey` is very likely correct.  I located a [Susanna Grigsby](http://www.wikitree.com/wiki/Grigsby-402) married to a Jacob King Remey (then deceased) and living in Bardstown, Nelson, Kentucky during the time of the signature in 1814.